# UI5 - Trouble configuring Karma configuration file for UI5

Tags: sapui5, karma-runner

I just started with karma runner, would like to use it to run my unit tests. The structure of my application is pretty standard, yet I have trouble setting up the ***karma.conf.js*** file. I try to direct karma to my `allTests.js` file which references all unit test files (when tested through `unitTests.qunit.html` file, all works as expected). Path to my `allTests.js` file

```
webapp/test/unit/allTests.js
```

And this is how the relevant section of `karma.conf.js` file looks like:

```
config.set({    
    openui5: {
      path: 'https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.65.1/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
    },

    client: {
      openui5: {
        tests: [
          'test/unit/allTests'
        ],
        config: {
          language: 'EN',
          resourceroots: {
            'test': './webapp/test'
          }
        } 
      }
    },

    basePath: 'webapp',

    frameworks: ['qunit', 'openui5'],

    files: [
      { pattern: '**', included: false, served: true, watched: true }
    ],
```

When executed, I assumed that karma would be able to find the `allTests.js` file, however, it throws this error.

```
03 07 2019 14:50:48.462:WARN [web-server]: 404: /webapp/test/unit/allTests.js
Firefox 66.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
Error: failed to load 'test/unit/allTests.js' from ./webapp/test/unit/allTests.js: 404 - Not Found at https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.65.1/resources/sap-ui-core.js:86:37
```

Does someone see where is the problem? Is the fact that I am using `CDN` for `sap-ui-core.js` somehow messing with the paths and is the system looking for the `AllTests.js` file on the openui.hana server. And if yes, how to fix it?

Comment: `webapp/test/unit/AllTests.js` has an upper case A, it does not in config, which has a lower case a.

Comment: sorry, my fault, the file is actually called allTests.js. Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. All I had to do was to folow the tutorial - https://help.sap.com/viewer/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/7.52.3/en-US/ae448243822448d8ba04b4784f4b09a0.html

The problem was that the /base/ route used in the tutorial is actually the route to the basePath in the conf file, I haven't found explained it anywhere but it seems to work. So I had to update the resourceroots section and use base in it. So now the file looks like this

```
config.set({    
    openui5: {
      path: 'https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.65.1/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
    },

    client: {
      openui5: {
        tests: [
          'test/unit/allTests'
        ],
        config: {
          language: 'EN',
          resourceroots: {
            'test': './base/test'
          }
        } 
      }
    },

    basePath: 'webapp',

    frameworks: ['qunit', 'openui5'],

    files: [
      { pattern: '**', included: false, served: true, watched: true }
    ],
```